# Why get incorrect file path when use mod rewrite in locahost?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, localhost

Why get incorrect file path when use mod rewrite in locahost ?

test.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="localhost">
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="test.jpg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^test/([^-]*)$ /test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

when call page `localhost/test/111` file path of `test.jpg` still `localhost/test/test.jpg`

but when call page `localhost/test.php?id=111` it's work good show file path `localhost/test.jpg`

How can call page `localhost/test/111` and show file path `localhost/test.jpg` ?

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/test/test.jpg` where `localhost` is the **domain name** (not a folder). Indeed, base should be

```
<base href="/">
```